# Error: element (body) is not in DOM or there is no element(body) with text "NameTest000"

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce

I am doing an assignment and have to create a smaller version of ecomerce website. To test it I was given a link to a their autoQA tester which gives me the following problem.

Error: element (body) is not in DOM or there is no element(body) with text "NameTest000" after 4 sec.

This error is given three times for "NameTest001" and "NameTest002". Alonside these errors the last error I was given is:

Element "delete-checkbox" was not found in text|CSS|XPath.

The thing is when I push it on the server it works as it should so I don't understand what exactly I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

I'll link to the github repository:

https://github.com/kn000x001/scandiweb-test-nika

I'll also add the image of the error[image]

[image]

Comment: can u give more information ? which framwork you using , it seems like missing something

Comment: I didn't use any framework. Maybe that's the main problem. that's why something might be missing. I can use react or vue though in accordance to the assignment.